# CXF Webclient parses xml to unknown schema

Tags: java, xml, cxf

I have a CXF WebClient which attempts to read an XML request from a REST service.

I am using the code:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(baseURL);
String authorizationHeader = "Basic "+ org.apache.cxf.common.util.Base64Utility.encode(("user:password").getBytes());
client.header("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).path(path);
System.out.println(client.get(String.class));
return client.get(Skill.class);
```

The Skill class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "self",
    "skillId",
    "skillName"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Skill")
public class Skill implements RootObject{

    protected Self self;
    protected int skillId;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String skillName;

getters...setters...
}
```

The System.out.println returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Skill><self>http://192.168.45.159/adminapi/skill/4</self><skillId>4</skillId><skillName>ICD2</skillName></Skill>
```

But i get the exception:

```
com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 1; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Skill"). Expected elements are <{}link>,<{}nameUriPair>,<{}trigger>
```

It seems like it is trying to parse the Skill into something else, which seems to contain link, nameUriPair and trigger.
I have no such class.
(I did indeed check the import, it IS my skill, and not something else)

I have tried with the following artifacts in both version 3.0.2 and 3.1.5

GroupID:

org.apache.cxf

ArtifactIDs:

cxf-rt-rs-client

cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs

cxf-rt-transports-http

Answer (score 0):

I'm obviously way too late here, but I think the problem is in:

```
return client.get(Skill.class);
```

I reckon what needs to be done instead is:

```
Response r = client.get();
Skill skill = (Skill) r.readEntity(Skill.class);
```